# Access 2007 selected value on combobox not displaying on more than one record

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have a ComboBox that displays a list of major occupations; when an occupation is selected its corresponding code is saved to a TextBox beside it. A further ComboBox for minor occupations is next, and the options shown in it are dependent on the option selected in the first ComboBox. As for the first, when a minor occupation is selected its code is saved to a linked TextBox. The selection and Requery for the second ComboBox was working fine, but now as you move from record to record on the form, the second ComboBox is blank although the TextBox is showing the code that was saved when the initial selection was made. So whichever record had the occupation selected most recently has both its ComboBoxes filled, but the previous records have only the first filled. Any ideas?

Comment: Couldn't see how to do this without ComboBoxes, the major list has 25 items and the minor list 90 before it is filtered. Sorted the problem however with the replication of the event code in Current.

Comment: Or thought I did! All fields were showing until the form was shut down and opened again, now I'm being asked to enter parameter value for the combobox before the form will launch.

Comment: OK, think the problems were linked to a wider issue - everything went haywire yesterday afternoon. Reverted to a previous version and put the Requery on Current and everything back to normal (fingers crossed).

Comment: @HansUp: Since you've been able to help with various problems associated with this database, here's another: how do people with large databases cope with Access? I've already faced one redesign because it threw its hands up over too many joins, and now I've hit the same wall again. How do people get round this other than have a completely unnormalised database with one huge table for all data? Would love to be back using MySQL and PHP, but the employer says this has to be done in Access due to sensitive data.

Comment: You would need to help me understand what you mean by large.  Size of MDB/ACCDB file greater than 1 GB?  50K lines of code?  Tables with million rows?  If the scope of the largeness problem is limited to complex joins, we'd need to examine schema.  I don't know whether you can frame this as a suitable SO question (meaning it won't get closed), but it's not reasonable to discuss this with comments.  Perhaps another Stack Exchange site (super user or database) might be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put some code in the On Current event of the form to requery the second combo box